# Chrome tab.create and capture screenshot of new created tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I have an issue with capturing a newly created tab in chrome.

I create the new tab with chrome.tabs.create and pass the tabid to my callback function which captures it.

```
function createtab(url) {
chrome.tabs.create({'url': url,'active':false}, function(tab) {

       captureWindowTab((tab.id);

});
}
```

```
function captureWindowTab(tabid) {

chrome.tabs.update(tabid, {}, function() {
     chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab(27, {format:"png"}, function(dataUrl) {


                     capturecallback(dataUrl);


    });
});

}
```

```
function capturecallback(dataurl) {

console.log(dataurl);

}
```

It works ONLY when i do it on current existing tabs. i cannot get it to work on newly created tabs. always returns undefined.

I dont understand whats the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved it like this:

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabid , info) {
      //console.log('loading tab'+tabid);

      if(info.status == "complete") {

      chrome.tabs.get(tabid,function(tab) {


        chrome.topSites.get(function(sites){ 


          tab.url = NewTab.getHostFromUrl(tab.url);

          console.log(tab.url);

          //console.log('loaded '+tab.url);

          for (var i = 8 - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

              sites[i].url = NewTab.getHostFromUrl(sites[i].url);

              //console.log('checking '+sites[i].url);

              if(tab.url == sites[i].url && tab.url != 'newtab') {

                chrome.tabs.update(tabid, {'highlighted':true,'active':true}, function(tab){

                     chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab(chrome.windows.WINDOW_ID_CURRENT, {format:"jpeg","quality":30}, function(dataUrl) {
                        // add data URL to array
                          if(dataUrl) {

                            console.log('its a winner!');

                            window.localStorage['topsite_'+encodeURI(NewTab.getHostFromUrl(tab.url))+'_thumbnail'] = dataUrl;
                            NewTab.getTopSites();


                          }

                        });




                });





              }

          };


       });



    });

  }
```

});

Answer (score 0):

Based on the documentation it seems you need the host permission (or all hosts permission) to be able to capture it. See the docuemtation at:

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#method-captureVisibleTab

Do you have the host permission or all hosts permission set?

I think you might also need the "tabs" permission, if you don't already have it.